# How to post data using write_http plugin of collectd even though buffer is not filled completely?

Tags: c, collectd

I am using collectd with write_http plugin. 
I have configured it and it is working properly.
Here is what I understand from its working-

It totally depends on buffer size i.e. when buffer fills it posts data to given url in configuration file.

I want to post data once all commands get executed irrespective to buffer size.

Is it possible to post data after execution of all commands and without filling buffer size?

Comment: I need something similar too. Were you able to accomplish this?